# Website Session Analysis

Tags: apache, language-agnostic, google-analytics, session-state, analysis

I'd like to know the best way to deep dive into the flow of my users. For example, I have 4 pages in my flow, how can I analyze which users abandon on which step? I can definitely do it by hand with logging, etc, but I'd rather use an off the shelf solution.

I have apache request logs, as well as google analytics. Can these analyze users as sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Google Analytics.

The flow of the users are called a funnel, which you have to set up in Google Analytics, the metric you get out is called Target Conversion Rate.

You can learn more about it at http://www.google.com/support/conversionuniversity/

Comment: Thank you. One problem is that my flow is doing two OAuths, which just 302 my users to external pages and don't load the analytics. Can I make a call on the server to google analytics to still record these?

Comment: Thanks for the accept. By "external page" I assume pages on servers that you have little or no control over. You probably can't get google to track your users through that site, because the urchin will be different if those pages run the google stuff at all. But the idea must be that the users are redirected back to you, possibly to the same URL, right? Then you can track that they have completed a step in your funnel, even if it's on the same url. I'm making a lot of assumptions here... More about this stuff on https://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55576

Comment: My flow is: (/, 200) (/twitter, 302) http://twitter.com (/twitter/callback, 302) (/meme, 302) http://meme.yahoo.com (/meme/callback, 302) (/done, 302) (/panel, 200). So there are really only 2 pages that are 200s. I want to know when /twitter/callback fails, or how often people don't come back from http://twitter.com . Can I serve something even when I'm 302ing users?

Comment: How about putting a page between the twitter and meme steps of your flow? It could say "Great, next task is Meme". Then you'll find out if you lost them at twitter or at meme. You could also serve a jumppage that tells them that they'll be sent to twitter i 5 seconds, this jumppage could be tracked. That turns your 302s into 200s.

A 302 doesn't contain any html or javascript, so you can't really track them with google analytics when 302. You would have to buy or develop something, but I'm not so sure you need it.